# Проверка орфографии и пунктуации

Tags: орфография

Проверьте пожалуйста орфографию и пунктуацию

```
В мире очень много разных языков, но из них больше всего выделяются мировые языки. Это те, на которых говорят, не только в странах для которых эти языки создавались, но и в других.  Их функции, облегчить общение между жителями разных стран. Один из таких языков, это русский. На нём разговаривает большое количество людей, на нём написаны великие произведения литературы. Что бы жители разных стран смогли читать литературу, написанную на русском, была создана организация МАПРЯЛ. Она выпускает курсы и учебники помогающие выучить русский язык людям в разных странах.
```

Comment: Ошибки есть, в пунктуации - точно.

В орфографии, пожалуй, только "Что бы" - надо вместе.

Comment: Спасибо )))

Answer (score 2):

В мире очень много разных языков, среди них  выделяются мировые языки. Это те, на которых говорят не только в странах, для которых эти языки создавались, но и в других.  Их функция(лучше сказать ЗАДАЧА) - облегчить общение между жителями разных стран. Один из таких языков - русский. На нём разговаривает большое количество людей, на нём написаны великие произведения литературы. Чтобы жители разных стран смогли читать литературу, написанную на русском, была создана организация МАПРЯЛ. Она выпускает  учебники и организует курсы, помогающие выучить русский язык людям в разных странах.